# How to get RowHandle (when it becomes valid) of new row of the grid (devexpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a grid, when user adds new row and is editting it, i want to pop-up a Save/Discard current chanegs option message when he tries to shift focus to another row.

Problem is I am unable to get handle of new row, so that i could do if prevFocusHanlde == newRowHandle && editModeOn

I only have the -214... as newrow handle which is default, but after row validation, grid geenrates a new valid rowhandle for this new row. **Where to record that ?**
Tried doing in RowUpdated, but it doesnt get called and by that time handle hasnt updated.

Comment: Can you piece of code? It will make clear picture what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an end-user starts to edit the new item row/card, the [ColumnView.InitNewRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_InitNewRowtopic.aspx) event is raised. You can handle this event to initialize particular fields within the new record. Once focus has moved to another row, the newly added row is added to the datasource and a blank new item row is displayed. The [ValidateRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ValidateRowtopic) event is raised when a modified row is about to lose focus. Handle this event to specify whether row data is valid, and whether focus movement is allowed (you can use the [ColumnView.IsNewItemRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_IsNewItemRowtopic) method to determine whether the specified row is the New Item Row). Immediately after the row was added, **its handle is equal to [BaseView.DataRowCount](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_DataRowCounttopic.aspx) - 1**.

Related topics:

- [New Item Row Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752)
- [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642)
- [Adding and Deleting Records](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752)
- [Validating Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument749)

Comment: I thought of doing this Count way, but didnt know that it was standard. i ddint want to depend on undocumented feature. Still, now I worked around by having own custom hidden field in the row. I am confident the BaseView.DataRowCount - 1 way will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I understand from question you want to do something like below:

```
List<int> rowIndex = new List<int>();
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!rowIndex.Contains(e.RowIndex))
    {
          rowIndex.Add(e.RowIndex);
          MessageBox.Show("Are you want to save changes?", "Save Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    }            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following function.

```
    public static bool IsCorrectRowHandle(GridView view, int rowHandle)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            System.Data.DataRow row = view.GetDataRow(rowHandle);
            if (row != null)
                result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Using the function;

```
            if (bgwInvoiceDetails.RowCount > 0)
            {
                if (ADevExpress.DevExpressMethods.IsCorrectRowHandle(bgwInvoiceDetails, GridControl.NewItemRowHandle))
                {
                    bgwInvoiceDetails.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, colExchangeType, leExchangeCode.EditValue);
                    bgwInvoiceDetails.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, colExchangePrice, teExchangePrice.EditValue);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < bgwInvoiceDetails.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (ADevExpress.DevExpressMethods.IsCorrectRowHandle(bgwInvoiceDetails, i))
                        bgwInvoiceDetails.SetRowCellValue(i, colExchangePrice, teExchangePrice.EditValue);
                }
            }
```